# Text Marquee from right to left

Tags: wpf, textblock

I am using the following code to move the text in TextBlock from right to left:-

```
ThicknessAnimation ThickAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation();
ThickAnimation.From = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
ThickAnimation.To = new Thickness(-TextGraphicalWidth, 0, 0, 0);
ThickAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
ThickAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40);
TextBlockMarquee.BeginAnimation(TextBlock.MarginProperty, ThickAnimation);
```

The problem I am having is this code works perfectly for a text whose width is less then that of screen. But for text whose width is greater then screen the text flickers a lot(Flickering increases when text contains unicode characters like: "\u25Bc").

here:- 
TextGraphicalWidth is width of original text.
TextLenghtGraphicalWidth is width of text after appending text to original text.

How can I handle this?

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Canvas ClipToBounds="True" Name="canMain" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=canMain, Path=ActualWidth}" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="TextBlockMarquee" Text="This is my animated text with special characters:" />
            <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock ClipToBounds="True" FontSize="22" Name="TextBoxMarquee" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Text="" />
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Name="TextBlockMarqueenew" Text="This is my animated text without special characters:" />
            <Border Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock ClipToBounds="True" FontSize="22" Name="TextBoxMarquee1" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Text="" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TickerDemoNew
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for TickerMaxTextBlock.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class TickerMaxTextBlock : Window
{
    StringBuilder s,s1;
    string TexttoScroll, TexttoScroll1;
    public TickerMaxTextBlock()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(TextBoxMarquee,TextFormattingMode.Ideal);
        UseLayoutRounding = true;
        TextBoxMarquee.Inlines.Add(new Run("I have attached herewith the full implementation of Custom TextBox class (TextBoxEx) in a word file. In the implementation when Tooltip is opening, it is checking whether text has truncated or not.  If text has not truncated then tooltip won’t be displayed (as it is not necessary because full text is anyway visible). Also, in order to show the tooltip, text property of the Textblock should be bound with the tooltip. ") { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
        TextBoxMarquee.Inlines.Add(new Run(" Despite of all the interop support available sometimes you will still come across some tricky issues which will be difficult to overcome. One such problem I faced recently. I had to configure the Dialog with MFC PropertySheet control. This PropertySheet control was holding few Property pages. These property pages didn’t had any MFC controls as content but hosting the user controls developed in WPF. First I will write very briefly about how to load the WPF user control inside the MFC container and then I will explain about my tricky problem and how I fixed it.") { Foreground = Brushes.Green });
    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        double TextGraphicalWidth = 0;
        foreach (var str in TextBoxMarquee.Inlines)
        {
            TextGraphicalWidth = TextGraphicalWidth + new FormattedText(((Run)str).Text, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(str.FontFamily.ToString()), str.FontSize, str.Foreground).WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace;
        }

        double TextLenghtGraphicalWidth = 0;

        while (TextLenghtGraphicalWidth < TextBoxMarquee.ActualWidth)
        {

            TextBoxMarquee.Inlines.Add(new Run("I have attached herewith the full implementation of Custom TextBox class (TextBoxEx) in a word file. In the implementation when Tooltip is opening, it is checking whether text has truncated or not.  If text has not truncated then tooltip won’t be displayed (as it is not necessary because full text is anyway visible). Also, in order to show the tooltip, text property of the Textblock should be bound with the tooltip. ") { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
            TextBoxMarquee.Inlines.Add(new Run(" Despite of all the interop support available sometimes you will still come across some tricky issues which will be difficult to overcome. One such problem I faced recently. I had to configure the Dialog with MFC PropertySheet control. This PropertySheet control was holding few Property pages. These property pages didn’t had any MFC controls as content but hosting the user controls developed in WPF. First I will write very briefly about how to load the WPF user control inside the MFC container and then I will explain about my tricky problem and how I fixed it.") { Foreground = Brushes.Green });

            foreach (var str in TextBoxMarquee.Inlines)
            {
                TextLenghtGraphicalWidth = TextLenghtGraphicalWidth + new FormattedText(((Run)str).Text, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(str.FontFamily.ToString()), str.FontSize, str.Foreground).WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace; 
            }


        }




        TextBoxMarquee.Inlines.Add(new Run("I have attached herewith the full implementation of Custom TextBox class (TextBoxEx) in a word file. In the implementation when Tooltip is opening, it is checking whether text has truncated or not.  If text has not truncated then tooltip won’t be displayed (as it is not necessary because full text is anyway visible). Also, in order to show the tooltip, text property of the Textblock should be bound with the tooltip. ") { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
        TextBoxMarquee.Inlines.Add(new Run(" Despite of all the interop support available sometimes you will still come across some tricky issues which will be difficult to overcome. One such problem I faced recently. I had to configure the Dialog with MFC PropertySheet control. This PropertySheet control was holding few Property pages. These property pages didn’t had any MFC controls as content but hosting the user controls developed in WPF. First I will write very briefly about how to load the WPF user control inside the MFC container and then I will explain about my tricky problem and how I fixed it.") { Foreground = Brushes.Green });


        double totalWidth = 0;
        foreach (var newStr in TextBoxMarquee.Inlines)
        {
            totalWidth = totalWidth + new FormattedText(((Run)newStr).Text, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(newStr.FontFamily.ToString()), newStr.FontSize, newStr.Foreground).WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace; 
        }
        MessageBox.Show((TextLenghtGraphicalWidth + TextBoxMarquee.ActualWidth).ToString());
        MessageBox.Show((TextLenghtGraphicalWidth + TextGraphicalWidth).ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(totalWidth.ToString());

        ThicknessAnimation ThickAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation();
        ThickAnimation.From = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        ThickAnimation.To = new Thickness(-TextGraphicalWidth, 0, 0, 0);
        ThickAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        ThickAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((50 * (totalWidth)) / TextBoxMarquee.ActualWidth));
        TextBoxMarquee.BeginAnimation(TextBlock.MarginProperty, ThickAnimation);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: I can't seem to provoke that particular error/flickering you are mentioning. I even tried adding "\u25Bc" and making the stringtext wider than the screen. :/ can you perhaps paste some more code. For instance some of your xaml :P

Comment: hey I have added the Xaml

Comment: Try set `Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(ThickAnimation, 60);` or try other values. [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.setdesiredframerate.aspx).

Comment: I still get nothing, and you are not doing anything else in code behind? Can you perhaps give me the string you are adding to the textblock just to see if that does anything :P

Comment: Ok I will try it. Hey I have also added the code behind I am using. Please try it by adding the special characters in between.

Comment: my code behind has it...

Comment: Okay, I see the problem. I'll check it out, but first i'll go to lunch.. hopefully it's just a small thing you've overseen ;)

Comment: Ok that would be great

Comment: Both textblocks/textboxes are actually flickering. It's not just the one with big text.. It's just easier to see in that one. I'm not sure why you use Inline aswell, havn't tried this, so i'm not aware of the effects or trouble it could cause.

I think it's your stringbuilder that is autocorrecting your string or something. I have a hard time finding the issue, only thing I know right now is, that the inlines &OR stringbuilder are the problem. because if you remove the inlines and do it like I showed you last time it works as it should, however the string colors are not showing ...

Comment: Ya I am using inlines as I need parts of strings with varrying colours.

Comment: Ok I will try avoiding the use of string builder

Comment: I'm not a 100% since I never use it myself, but you probably need to figure out what happens to the string after it is build or something like that.

Comment: Hi Max. I removed the use of string builder. But the text is still flickering. I need to use inlines as I need to add text with varrying colours.

Comment: I have put my updated code